# undefined method `send_activation_email'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

after a few additions to my code (that didn't actually touch any of the code that's raising the issue now) a specific part of my sign-up process stopped working.

This part is from Michael Hartl's tutorial, and it had worked fine but now is raising me a problem whenever I try to sign-up a new user through a normal sign-up form (I added signups through FB G+ and Linkedin and they all work).

I get a **undefined method `send_activation_email'** when submit the form. I didn't check the method for some time as I was adding the other signups for social media, but these have their own paths and work through the sessions controller, not the users controller so they shouldn't really create a problem.

In my user model I have:

```
def send_activation_mail
    UserMailer.account_activation(self).deliver_now
end
```

Then in my users controller:

```
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
        @user.send_activation_email
        flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
        redirect_to root_url
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

And the view that generates the form:

```
<div class="row center">
    <div class="col-md-4 center mg-top col-md-offset-4">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

        <%= f.label :first_name %>
        <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: 'form-control' %>

        <%= f.label :last_name %>
        <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: 'form-control' %>

        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

        <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Re-type your password" %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

        <%= f.submit "Create an account", class: "btn btn-primary margin-25" %>
    <% end %>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Whenever I sign-up a new user, the post action goes through and the user is actually created but I get this Action Controller error:

```
undefined method `send_activation_email' for #<User:0x007f90064bd5a0>

Extracted source (around line #19):
17
18
19
20
21
22

        @user = User.new(user_params)
        if @user.save
            @user.send_activation_email
            flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
            redirect_to root_url
        else
```

A read-out from ruby's console tells me the user has been created (and the error is raised in the conditional if-save ...):

```
#<User id: 133, first_name: "Txe", last_name: "Pah", email: "teste@email.com", password_digest: "$2a$10$PLY4ZleCtUO0cLdRjIErBuF0j46YQBq1g3Krsf5T.i8...", created_at: "2015-07-25 03:41:49", updated_at: "2015-07-25 03:41:49", remember_digest: nil, admin: false, activation_digest: "$2a$10$voHnNYgzI2jazwRK3EiM6uKsel8Fieb.9HEVs29X8ml...", activated: false, activated_at: nil, reset_digest: nil, reset_sent_at: nil, link: nil, fb: false, fb_id: nil, fb_image: nil, gplus: false, gplus_id: nil, gplus_image: nil, lin: false, lin_id: nil, lin_image: nil, gender: "Unidentified", avatar: nil>
```

What I don't get is why the send_activation_email is not working as it is defined in the User model.

Could somebody help me or has experienced the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `send_activation_mail` in `User` model not `send_activation_email`. Changing it to

```
@user.send_activation_mail
```

should solve your problem.

Comment: Omg, thank you so much Pavan, I really feel stupid now. I looked into the names (when searching for answers many people overlooked exactly the same) but I dunno why I really  didn't see, I guess too much time looking at the same code and my brain filling in the gaps for me - thanks again!